# Change the number of columns in a Woocommerce template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a page template for a Woocommerce site and I would like to display a row of four products inside that template but it's defaulting to three

The code:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => 4
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
      echo "<div class='columns-4'>";
      echo "<ul class='products columns-4'>";
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
      echo "</ul>";
      echo "</div>";
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
```

I can see that its adding the classes 'first' and 'last' to every first and third item in the row I just need to know how to change that.

Thanks